# How does Windows schedule power on's and automatic updates at night?

Tags: windows, motherboard, bios, power, wake-on-lan

What technology does it use? Does it have to be connected to the internet so Microsoft can send a wake-on-lan package? I don't think so. Does it somehow schedule it in the motherboard and wake after the motherboard clock reaches a certain point?

Comment: Any modern PC supports wake-up timers that works on hardware level. If you explore power options settings in control panel you will find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Sleep state (S0) is a low power "working state" that a computer can go to sleep but be woken up by such events as a Windows scheduled tasks and other events.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-wake-sources